# PdfFileReader.getFields() returns {} | django

Tags: python, django, pypdf

I'm trying to read a pdf form with django. The point is that in another view of my views.py I've succeed into do it by using PyPDF2 and its PdfFileReader.getFields() method.
Now the problem is that the reading is not working properly: I've checked with adobe acrobat and the file still is a form with actually fields, so I don't really have any idea of what could be the problem.

I'm attaching here the relevant portion of the code:

```
if request.method == "POST":
        form = Form(request.POST, request.FILES) # the form refer to a model called 'New Request'
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            File = request.FILES['File'].name
            full_filename = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/media', File)
            f = PdfFileReader(full_filename)
            fields = f.getFields()
            fdfinfo = dict((k, v.get('/V', '')) for k, v in fields.items())
            k = creare_from_pdf2(request, fdfinfo, pk) # this is a custom function 
            nr = NewRequest.objects.all() #I'm deleting the object uploaded because it won't be useful anymore
            nr.delete()
            os.remove(full_filename)
```

If I display `print(fdfinfo)` it actually shows `{}`. This of course is leading to error when fdfinfo passes into the 'create_from_pdf_2' function. I don't really know what the problem could be, also because in another view I made exactly the same and it works:

```
if request.method=='POST':
        form = Form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            uploaded_filename = request.FILES['File'].name
            full_filename = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/media', uploaded_filename)
            f = PdfFileReader(full_filename)
            fields = f.getFields()
            fdfinfo = dict((k, v.get('/V', '')) for k, v in fields.items())
            k=create_from_pdf1(request, fdfinfo)
            if k==1:
                return HttpResponse('<html><body>Something went wrong</html></body>')
            nr = NewRequest.objects.all()
            nr.delete()
            os.remove(full_filename)
```

Maybe is there a way to display the errors of PdfFileReader?

**UPDATING**

The new file that I'm trying to reading is firstly modified in the sense that some (BUT NOT ALL!) fields are filled with PdfFileWriter, and the one filled are set then to only readable. Could this operation have influenced the performances of PdfFileReader? I'm attaching the correspondent view

```
att = MAIN.objects.get(id=pk)
    file_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'nuova_form.pdf')
    input_stream = open(file_path, "rb")
    pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(input_stream, strict = False)
    if "/AcroForm" in pdf_reader.trailer["/Root"]:
        pdf_reader.trailer["/Root"]["/AcroForm"].update(
            {NameObject("/NeedAppearances"): BooleanObject(True)})

    pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()
    set_need_appearances_writer(pdf_writer)
    if "/AcroForm" in pdf_writer._root_object:
        # Acro form is form field, set needs appearances to fix printing issues
        pdf_writer._root_object["/AcroForm"].update(
            {NameObject("/NeedAppearances"): BooleanObject(True)})
data_dict1 = { # my text fields
    }
data_dict2 = { # my booleancheckbox fields }

for i in range(0,6): #The pdf file has 6 pages
        pdf_writer.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(i))
        page = pdf_writer.getPage(i)
        
        # update form fields
        pdf_writer.updatePageFormFieldValues(page, data_dict1)
        for j in range(0, len(page['/Annots'])):
            writer_annot = page['/Annots'][j].getObject()
            for field in data_dict1:
                if writer_annot.get('/T') == field:
                    writer_annot.update({
                        NameObject("/Ff"): NumberObject(1)    # make ReadOnly
                    })
        # update checkbox fields
        updateCheckboxValues(page, data_dict2)
    output_stream = BytesIO()
    pdf_writer.write(output_stream)

    return output_stream

def updateCheckboxValues(page, fields):

    for j in range(0, len(page['/Annots'])):
        writer_annot = page['/Annots'][j].getObject()
        for field in fields:
            if writer_annot.get('/T') == field:
                writer_annot.update({
                    NameObject("/V"): NameObject(fields[field]),
                    NameObject("/AS"): NameObject(fields[field])
                })
```

Comment: when you have ```fields = f.getFields()```,  what does ```fields``` contain?

Comment: I've displayed `print(fields)` and shows `{}`.

Comment: According to https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileReader.html  you could use the ```fileobj``` parameter to store whatever fields that the pdffilereader found.

Comment: It is empty too

Comment: Could maybe because this file pdf that I'm trying to reading is firstly written with PdfFileWriter? This could influence the reading?

Answer (score 0):

I got similar results when trying to do a straightforward read of a PDF form using Python and PyPDF2.  The PDF form had been created using Libre Writer and was a single page with about 50 text fields on it.  When I ran the getFields() method on the reader object I was getting the same issue -- it was returning an empty dict object.

I thought there might be a limitation on the number of fields and tried removing some for testing, but got the same result.  Then when looking at it I noticed the fieldnames were all pretty long:  txtLabMemberFirstName01, txtLabMemberLastName01, txtPrincipalInvestigatorFirstName, etc.

I shortened all the fields' names (e.g., "txtLMFN01") and PyPDF2 started working again as expected.